# python regex extraction of fields using re.compile

Tags: python, regex

```
array= ['gmond 10-22:13:29','bash 12-25:13:59']

regex = re.compile(r"((\d+)\-)?((\d+):)?(\d+):(\d+)$")

for key in array :
    res = regex.match(key)
    if res:
        print res.group(2)
        print res.group(5)
        print res.group(6)
```

I know I am  doing it wrong . But I tried several things , and failed. Can some one help me how can I fetch the patter macthes using group or any better way. I want to fetch the digits if the pattern is matched. This works so smooth with re.search but have to do it using re.compile in this case. Appreciate ur help.

Comment: What exactly is `array` is it a `list` (with `[]`), a `dict` (with keys), or a `string` (which you want to parse using regexp)? And what exactly are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: @jadkik94: it is a list with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` if you are sure of the format the elements of `array`:

```
>>> import re
>>> array = ["10-22:13:29", "12-25:13:59"]
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\d+")
>>> for key in array:
...     res = regex.findall(key)
...     if res:
...         print res
...
['10', '22', '13', '29']
['12', '25', '13', '59']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `search` with compile just as well. (`match` matches only at the beginning of the )

Answer (score 1):

You are catching `-` and `:`, also, you have redundant brackets. Here's the code with modified regex:

```
import re

array = ["10-22:13:29", "12-25:13:59"]

regex = re.compile(r"^(\d+)\-?(\d+):?(\d+):?(\d+)$")
for key in array:
    res = regex.match(key)
    if res:
        print res.groups()
```

prints:

```
('10', '22', '13', '29')
('12', '25', '13', '59')
```

See, all digits are extracted properly.